# How to restart a launchd service automatically if it exits with 78 exit code

Tags: mac-osx, launchd, launchctl

I am loading a c binary using launchd service. It should be relaoded every time when system restarts. Below is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.example</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/etc/example/usr/sbin/example_cbinary</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Some times, it is exiting with 78 exit code.

```
launchctl list | grep example
-   78  com.example
```

I am unable to find root cause for this.  As this happens once in hundred times. 
To resolve this i am unloading and loading this service. I wanted it to automatically unload and load whenever it exits with 78 status.

Any help is highly appreciable

Thanks in Adavance

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old article, but I had the same problem and could solve it by writing a python script which grep the 78 and call a system command e.g. shell script to unload and load the service. And put this script in crontab

```
pseudocode:

#!/bin/bash

export PATH=(your_$PATH)

    erg = `launchctl list | grep example | grep 78`
    if [ $erg = '78']
    then
        launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDeamons/example.plist
        launchctl load /Library/LaunchDeamons/example.plist
        # perhaps also
        launchctl start example
    fi
```

And if that script will be executed correctly on the shell then put it into the crontab.

```
example cron entry:

* * * * * reload_example.sh (watch out for access rights and the new shitty security options)
```

Perhaps it is a usefull hint.